# Is it possible to train a neural network to identify only one type of object?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

I am new to neural networks. Is it possible to train a neural network to identify only one type of object? For instance, a table from a large set of images, where the neural network should be able to identify if new images are tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can train a NN to detect only one type of object like a table. However, you probably will not want to train such a NN from scratch by showing some examples of tables and non-tables. You will need to use **transfer learning** on a model already trained on several image classes and teach it to also recognize your new class. This transfer learning requires a smaller set of desired images. You may need to give it some negative examples also. You should explore transfer learning with **mobilenet**, **inception**, and other **pre-trained Tensorflow models** if you are willing to use **Python** and Tensorflow